# How to translate txt file settings into php array

Tags: php, arrays, file

I have text file containing values like this:

```
varname:
{
    varname2: value
    varname3: 
    {
       varname4: value
    }
}
```

I need to get this somehow into php array like this:

```
array(
   varname => array
   (
      varname2 => value
      varname3 => array
      (
          varname4 => value
      ) 
   )
)
```

How can i do this?

I have tried looping through file and trying to make values like that but it gets very tricky when there is multiple level array. Spent many hours without luck...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you (if you can) to change your file format to a JSON format, that is very similar to your format now:

```
{"varname":{"varname2":"value","varname3":{"varname4":"value"}}}
```

Then you can read the file and use json_decode to obtain the array in a very simple form. Here I write the code for decode json to array and echo it:

```
$s = file_get_contents('datos.js');
$ar = json_decode($s, true);
print_r($ar);
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much of a hack you want it to be. If you have a true defined format and want to be strict you'd start with a lexer. See http://wezfurlong.org/blog/2006/nov/parser-and-lexer-generators-for-php/ or https://github.com/nikic/Phlexy

On the other hand you could also make it in two steps (depending on how complicated the now shown use cases are).

1. Replace all leading spaces and replace `: \n{` with `: {` for easier parsing.
2. Write a recursive parsing function. In every line everything before `:` is the variable name, everything after the value. If the value is `{` to a recursion until `}` and use the result as the value.